# A linear system with solution $x=20$ and $y=20$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

It's almost New Year, and we want to surprise our math teacher. $2020$ is coming, and we want to wish her a Happy New Year in an interesting way. We have studied systems of linear equations and want to think of a system with solution $x=20$ and $y=20$. It must be a system of linear equations because of the only solution that we want.

$\begin{array}{|l} 
 a_1x+b_1y=d_1 \\  a_2x+b_2y=d_2  \end{array}$

I am not sure how to approach the problem. We haven't studied square matrices or the Cramer's rule. We've studied the Graphic method, the Substitution method, and the Elimination method.

Comment: Just write down some equations $(x,y)=(20,20)$ must satisfy.  $4x-3y=20$, for instance, or $x+2y=60$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't want it to be that easy! I am not sure how it's called in English, but GT says that it's lay-up (or laying, placement). For example, when you have $(x+2y)^2$ in both equations of the system, you define a new variable $a=(x+2y)^2$ — something like this. I just don't want it to be too simple.

Comment: You said you wanted a linear system!  Are you allowing more complicated functions?

Comment: I thought that it must be a linear system because we want only one solution $(x,y)=(20,20)$. I just gave an example of the technique because I don't know its name. $$\begin{array}{|l} 
 4(x+2y)-(2x-3y)=5 \\  2(x+2y)+(2x-3y)=7  \end{array}$$ Let $$\begin{array}{|l} 
 x+2y=u \\  2x-3y=v  \end{array}...$$

Comment: That's still just a linear system (expand out the left sides).  Maybe you want something like $x^2+y^2=40(x+y-20)$ or, similarly, $x^2+2y^2=40(x+2y-30)$

Comment: @lulu, exactly. What can be the second equation of the system?

Comment: You don't need two equations.  For either of those two examples the only real solutions are $(x,y)=(20,20)$.

Comment: I really want it to be a system because this is what we are studying at the moment.

Comment: @Stellar I am confused. Do you want multiple equations and should they be linear?

Comment: @lulu I like the idea of expanding $(x-20)^2+(y-20)^2$ and $(x-20)^2+2(y-20)^2$. For extra trickiness, this can also be expanded to - for example - fourth powers

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, what exactly does confuse you? I think my post is fairly clear. I want a system with only solution $x=20$ and $y=20$. When did I say I want multiple equations?

Comment: In the question you say that you want a linear system but in the comments you suggest including expressions such as $(x+2y)^2$ which are not linear (also, you seem to have interest in the non-linear equations by @lulu). Additionally, here I wasn't clear, with "multiple equations" I just mean an equation system

Comment: Will you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Pick the coefficients $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$ that you like, and compute

$$d_1=20a_1+20b_1,\\d_2=20a_2+20b_2.$$