# A system of linear equations with solution $x=20$ and $y=20$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I am trying to come up with a system with solution $x=20$ and $y=20$. This is what I have now:

$$\begin{array}{|l} 3(x-3y)-(2x-3y)=-100 \\ 4(x-3y)+2(2x-3y)=-200\end{array}$$
The expected solution is to define $a=x-3y$ and $b=2x-3y$ and solve in this way. Do you think it's okay right now or the solution's obvious? How can I make it more complicated?

Comment: You can make it arbitrarily complicated, but also arbitrarily ugly. I still find $x-20=0$ and $y-20=0$ nicer than this. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475410/a-linear-system-with-solution-x-20-and-y-20). What about $x+y=40$ and $x+2y=60$?

Comment: I still don't understand what's wrong with my post that you are downvoting it! And what exactly in the system you do not like? That's why I am posting it. I have shown personal effort.

Comment: Who is downvoting a post here? I can't see this.

Comment: Someone did. ;)

Comment: Well, not me. :)

Comment: That's fine. I don't care if it was you or somebody else. I am just searching for help. What do you find ugly in my system?

Comment: Too many brackets, looks artificial.

Comment: Yes. That's because I don't want the system to be that easy. I followed this example in my textbook: $\begin{array}{|l} 4(x+2y)-(2x-3y)=5 \\  2(x+2y)+(2x-3y)=7 \end{array}$

Comment: Do you think I can improve it?

Comment: The system $(x^2-40x)(x^2+y^2+2)+400(x^2+y^2)=-800$ and $(y^2-40y)(x^2+y^2+1)+400(x^2+y^2)=-400$ has only one real solution $(x,y)=(20,20)$.

Comment: Thank you! How do you suggest to solve it? $a=x^2+y^2+1$ and $b=x^2+y^2$?

Comment: It's simple because the system can be written as $(x-20)^2(x^2+y^2+2)=0$ and $(y-20)^2(x^2+y^2+1)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is fine.

If you want to make it more complicated make it nonlinear.

For example $$ (2x-y)^2+(x+y)^2=2000, 3(2x-y)+(x+y)^2=1660$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Your system has $4$ solutions. I want the system to have only one $x=20$ and $y=20$.

Comment: Change the second equation to $(x-20)^2+(y-20)^2=0$

Answer (score -2):

Simplifying your system we get
$$x-6y=-100$$
$$4x-9y=-100$$
Multiplying the first equation by $-4$ and adding to the second we get
$$150y=300$$ so $y=20$ as you stated.

Comment: Actually , the O.P is not looking for a solution , but a question with $x=20,y=20$ as a solution.